# Unable to cascade delete to a Child entity using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have this project of a coupon system using spring boot and hibernate.
While trying to delete a company I want it to delete selectd company coupons and all purchased made by customer of those deleted coupons.

when using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`
it removes the company and its coupons with no problem, however, the purchase table with coupon ID still exists and has not been deleted.

I tried using `orphanRemoval=true`. But it doesn't do anything.
If I use `CascadeType.REMOVE` it just removes everything in purchase history including coupons purchase history from different companies.

Is there anyway of deleting all history of company using Hibernate/Spring annotations? or I should just use the native way.

I have `COMPANY` table which holds all companies
I have `COUPON`  table which holds all coupon and has a PK of coupon_id
I have `COUPONS_CUSTOMERS` table which holds the purchase history of customer and both columns are PK keys (customer_id - coupon_id). (this is the touble maker table).

**Company Class:**

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
@Data
//without this we get a circular dependency, while excluding coupons from to string we fix this problem
@ToString(exclude = "coupons")
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Company {

    @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        private int companyId;
        
        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        private String name;
    
        @Email(message = "Wrong email input. Please try again")
        @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String email;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @Size(min = 4, max = 8, message = "Password range must be between 4 - 8 digits")
        private String password;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Coupon> coupons;



    public Company(String name, String email, String password) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Company(int companyId, String name, String email, String password) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

**Remove Method:**

```
 public void deleteCompany(int id) throws CompanyDoesNotExistException {

        if (compRepo.existsById(id)) {

            compRepo.deleteById(id);

        } else {
            throw new CompanyDoesNotExistException();
        }

    }
```

**Coupon Class**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "coupons")
@Data()
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Coupon {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private int couponId;

    @ManyToOne(mappedby = "")
    private Company company;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    @FutureOrPresent(message = "\nInvalid date.\nDate must be present or future")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "end_date", nullable = false)
    @Future(message = "\nInvalid date.\nEnd date must be a future date")
    private Date endDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @PositiveOrZero( message = "Cannot add a negative amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Min(value = 10, message = "Price cannot be under 10$")
    private double price;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String image;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "coupons", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Customer> customers;


    public Coupon(Company company, Category category, String title, String description, Date startDate, Date endDate,
            @PositiveOrZero int amount, @Min(10) double price, String image) {
        this.company = company;
        this.category = category;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }
```

**Customer Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private int customerId;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Email(message = "Wrong email input, please try again")
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Size(min = 4, max = 8, message = "Password range must be between 4 -8 digits")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Coupon> coupons;

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void deleteCoupon(Coupon coupon) {
        this.coupons.remove(coupon);
    }
```

**Deleting Company**

```
admin.deleteCompany(1);
```

I do not get any exception, however, I cannot seem to find the solution to delete the whole history of the company even tho it removes companies coupons it still keeps the purchase of those coupons.

Hope I am clear. I could add additional information if needed.

**Repository:**

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Integer> {

    Company findCompanyByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);

    Company findCompanyByEmail(String email);

    Company findCompanyByName(String name);


}
```

Comment: Can you share your `deleteById` method?

Comment: @ansvir Hi, the method deleteById is from JpaRepository which extends my Repository interface. so its not actually written by me. anyway I have shared the repo

Comment: Are you using the latest Hibernate version 5.4.30? If so, and you still have the problem, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.